# string::c_str() and string::data() not working for conversion to const char*

Tags: c++

I have a map structure in a class that is defined as `std::map<const char*, double>`, and in the constructor, I add three elements all set to zero, with they keys "MR_WP", "MR_WM", and "MR_WC". I also have several access functions to the map, but before the access is performed, there is a function that checks to make sure the key actually exists in the map.

Basically, I have something that says:

```
if ( map.find(_key) == map.end() ) throw "error"
```

When I pass a const char* string into the access function such as getValue("MR_WP"), there is no error.

However, if I do it like this:

```
std::string str = "MR_WP";

double value = map.getValue( str.c_str() );

-or-

std::string str = "MR_WP";

double value = map.getValue( str.data() );
```

then the error is thrown. I tried both functions, because I thought that the error might have resulted from the null character. The reason I need to do it this way, is because I want to get the last letter of the key at runtime such as:

```
std::string type = getType();

std::string str = "MR_W" + type;

double value = map.getValue( str.c_str() ); //or with str.data()
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration and init of your map?

Comment: Please provide the declaration of your map's template parameters.  Your map _should_ be `std::map<std::string, int>`, and not `std::map::<const char*, int>, unless you've provided a specific comparison function for const char* that does a string compare.

Comment: Why on earth would you not make your map keyed on `std::string`?

Comment: What is the function signature (i.e., the declaration) for `getValue`?

Comment: If you need to key on strings (which is a perfectly valid requirement), look into using `unordered` containers -- but let's not get ahead of ourselves, let's find a solution to the original problem first.

Comment: The reason that I was using const char* instead of std::string for the map was that this is part of a larger project and there were legacy issues. I was told that I should use a const char* to work with another module. That said, I think casting it internally from a const char* to a std::string, and making it a map of strings is the right approach. So consider my problem solved. That said, do any of you have any idea why neither c_str() or string::data() would work?

Comment: @Max: Consider my answer accepted and mark it as such. :) It explains why C-style strings obtained through `c_str()` and `data()` didn't "work" for you.

Answer (score 13):

If your map is `std::map<char const*, int>`, then — by default — your keys are being compared by comparing pointers, not lexical value.

Recall what happens [when you do this](http://codepad.org/jVgyVjr3):

```
const char* str1   = "Some string";
const char  str2[] = "Some string";

std::cout << (str1 == str2 ? "true" : "false");
// Output: false
```

Use a `std::map<std::string, int>` instead; not only does it not sink you in a mire of ownership issues, but it comes with a ready-made comparator!

Comment: Ah! Got it! Thank you all for the quick replies.